# Filter variable values in grafana with dependent variable

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have two variables:

- Hostname: host1, host2, host3
- Process: processA, processB

I'd like to restrict the values the user is able to select on the graph depending on the process that is selected.

For example, if the process is `processA` let's only show option `host1`, and if the process is `processB` let's only show option `host2` and `host3`.

I couldn't find a way of doing this.

Much appreciated!